# Reducing line thickness / size in multiple qplot graphs in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wish to create 24 line plots on an A4 page in a high resolution png. I'm trying to do this using qplot and the grid.arrange function in the gridExtra library. My problem is that I can't reduce the thickness of the lines in each plot, below a certain threshold. Setting size=0 or size=0.0001 or whatever makes no difference; there seems to be a minimum that can't be crossed, and it's much thicker than I'd like. Increasing the size of the plot area works but then I have to rescale the resulting image. Can anyone please suggest an alternative? A minimal example is below.

```
library(ggplot2)    
library(gplots)
library(gridExtra)

a <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5)
b <- a^2

plot1 <- qplot(a, b, geom = c("point", "line"), pch=10) + 
             geom_point(size=0) + 
             geom_line(size=0)
png("filename.png", width=15, height=22, units = "cm", res = 900)

grid.arrange(
plot1,plot1,plot1,plot1,
plot1,plot1,plot1,plot1,
plot1,plot1,plot1,plot1,
plot1,plot1,plot1,plot1,
plot1,plot1,plot1,plot1,
plot1,plot1,plot1,plot1,
ncol=4)

dev.off()
```

Comment: Create a vector graphic (pdf, eps, svg or wmf)?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I tried that, but I run into other problems with pdf or postscript and my editing program (Inkscape). Where I have points marked as circles, if I save as pdf and open in Inkscape then it converts each circle into a lower case "q". And Inkscape seems incapable of handling postscript images created in R that are larger than A4. It's because of issues like these that I'd rather not have to do much image editing, especially as it's likely I'll want to change the data and/or layout at some later date. I was hoping there might be some simple solution in R.

Comment: Inkscape uses svg as its graphic format. Try that.

Comment: The best workaround I've come up with yet is to create a larger png and rescale in gimp.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your svg comment. I'll give that a go.

Comment: OK, that works: create an svg that's much bigger than A4 and then rescale it in Inkscape. It's still a little perplexing that a workaround is needed. Thanks for the help, @Roland.

Comment: I'm perplexed that you had this problem at all. When I run your code, I can't even _see_ the lines until I raise the size up to at least 0.01, and even then I have to squint.

Comment: @joran Probably depends on the OS ...

Comment: Interesting. I'm running Windows 7 and R x64 2.13.0.